# Add timeout error when comment fails to be submitted via the app

Tags: feature-request, bug, comments, android-app

Sometimes, comment posting is stuck: (e.g. when internet connection lags, internal API issues)

> [image: posting in progress]

In such cases, it just keeps loading... and loading... and loading, and never stops, forcing me to close the entire app.

Can you please add a timeout error e.g. after 10-20 seconds without response from the server?

Comment: Reason to downvote?

Comment: Maybe wrong wording, one can't decline a comment. Will edit it now to be correct. :)

Comment: Well, this is surely not a bug. Very few places offer the ability to cancel submission while it's being sent to server. Reworded and retagged.

Comment: @ShadowWizard in my case internet connection was fine. E.g. when Android app is failing (can't open posts, comments etc), I use web site and **everithing** is fine! I would blame API, but iOS app is working more stable. Hence it's a bug (in behaviour) mostly, not a feature-request. Every operation should take reasonable amount of time, if not - it should be canceled, not freezing forever.

Comment: Well.. the bug is that the app is "stuck". And no, I disagree that every action should have "cancel" option. Once you send something, it's being sent.

Comment: @ShadowWizard "cancel" should be automated by time in such cases. Every good application shouldn't stuck despite of internet connection quality, especisally when there's no issue with network at all in OS.

Comment: I do agree a timeout is expected, e.g. after 10-20 seconds we'll get error, that's the case in the web version of SE. But the focus of this question appeared to be on letting the user manually cancel the request.

Comment: @ShadowWizard my wording is still poor here :(

Comment: I can edit again if you want. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard edit, revote, comment, closed as duplicate :) question live cycle on SE.

Comment: Edited again. Now we can wait.... and wait.... and wait.

Comment: @ShadowWizard from 6 to 8 (rotated for pi/2) weeks

Comment: Nah... since the app is dead, we need to wait for Salvation, when the dead will arise from the ground and walk the earth again. ;)